# Graphs formed of vertices of distance $2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. Let $D_2(G)$ be the graph with vertex set $V$, and two vertices form an edge if and only if they have distance $2$ in the original graph $G$.

Note that, if $C_{2k+1}$ is the circle on $2k+1$ points for an integer $k\geq 2$, we have $C_{2k+1}\cong D_2(C_{2k+1})$.

**Question.** Is there a connected, non-[regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|>2$ such that $G\cong D_2(G)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the hexagon ABCDEF with the additional edge of AC has this property.  The first graph shows $G$ and the others show two views of $D_2(G)$.

[image: G]
[image: D_2(G) showing D_2]
[image: D_2(G) showing iso]

(Graphs courtesy of [NCTM](https://www.nctm.org/Classroom-Resources/Illuminations/Interactives/Graph-Creator/))

Comment: Brilliant, and thanks for the nice visualization!